# How to find all local extrema using multi-variate calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find all local extrema of $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$. That is, find their locations and values.

I started this problem but when I took the first derivative I got the critical points as $(0, 0)$. Then I took the second derivative and got $x= 2$ and $y= 2$. What do i do next? Please help me.

Comment: I think you have your answer. Can you sketch $f(x,y)=z=x^2+y^2$?

Comment: i mean i know that is a saddle point but is that all i have to do?

Comment: There is no saddle point. To sketch this plug in different values for $z$. Do you see a pattern?

Comment: @helycummin: If you are working on $\mathbb R^2$, the origin is absolute min and it is over, but if your domain be restricted then we have to consider additional points.

Comment: @user69810 i dont see what you are saying

Comment: @BabakS. what do you mean?

Comment: @helycummin Can $z<0$? What kind of curve do we get if we set $z=1$? What if we try different values for $z$? What if you set $x=0$?, How about $y$? Does this give you a picture of what the surface looks like?

Answer (score 1):

We have a local minimum at $(0,0)$. The mechanical way to determine this is to find where the the derivative is $0$ and apply the [second partial derivative test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test).

However, if we sketch the surface $\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3: z=x^2+y^2\}$ we see that we have a paraboloid that is opening upward and it becomes obvious that $(0,0)$ is a local minimum.